# How to determine how much weight should you start with for dumbbell squats and sit-ups as a beginner?

Tags: weightlifting, bodyweight-exercises, bodyweight

For an underweight skinny adult, how much weight is recommended? Is there any guide for this where I can read about it, and calculate it for me?

NOTE: If this question seems opinion based, kindly share the available sources if you know any, where I can read about this. That will be helpful.

Comment: Forget about weighted sit ups, perhaps until later if you have to. They can really hurt your spine. Before you think about how much weight to put on for any exercise, you should really learn the movement first. Start slow, start with the right form and then add significant weights. You should be able to pick this up fast once you are able to notice that you are using too much weight = your form is suffering. Since you are an adult, I'm assuming you have some level of judgement and don't attempt a 40kg per dumbbell benchpress on your first try and rip your arms off. Start slow and smart

Answer (score 1):

Start with 0 and add weight until it feels decently heavy, then keep doing it, and keep adding more weight or doing more repetitions after each week.

It will make you feel good.